# Finding faces around a vertex in CGAL?

Tags: cgal, tetrahedra

Not sure if the question is already answered. I am working with tethedral mesh (medit mesh)  file with CGAL. I need to find out the faces around the vertices in this mesh. So it will be a vertex-face iterator. Does anyone know if CGAL has this kind of iterator?

Comment: It's a bit tricky using the `C3T3` directly. Do you need the incident faces for each vertex?

Comment: I need the incident tetrahedrons.

Comment: If you need to do that for all vertices, in most cases you can iterate on the tets then iterate on the vertices of each tet (swap the two nested loops), in most cases it makes the code much simpler and much much faster (it does not apply if you need to do that for a single vertex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`finite_incident_cells`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html#a2b07df83a18c0dbd5dcdfa5fcf33d130) and test whether the cells are in the complex using [`is_in_complex`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classMeshComplex__3InTriangulation__3.html#a7b58574d2c8adfd81fa3b4f6eab1bbb5).